# Bulk Inserts with Service Stack & Ormlite

Tags: sql-server, servicestack, bulk, ormlite-servicestack

I am having trouble finding a good way to do fast bulk inserts in ServiceStacks Ormlite
I will be performing the inserts against SQL Azure.

The only batch inserts that I could find would be to do as follows:

```
using (IDbTransaction dbTrans = Db.OpenTransaction())
        {

            foreach (var mfm in MFMs)
            {
                Db.Insert<Metrics>(mfm);
            }

            dbTrans.Commit();
        }
```

But I am seeing no improvement in speed and I need to insert 20,000 records and it takes a tremendously long time.

Please advise if there is a good way to do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to check [SqlBulkCopy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519402/parallel-bulk-inserting-with-sqlbulkcopy-and-azure) (follow the link for some numbers when using it in SQL Azure)